# Is there some way to protect my php code of unauthorized use?

Tags: php, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obfuscating string values in PHP source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983709/obfuscating-string-values-in-php-source-code)

Well i got a php script and i need to protect it to no 1 edit it, how can i do it? is there some free way to do it?

EDIT: Some friend told me about bcompiler? someone already used it?

Comment: [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/).  Not free but if you have something to lose, it can be worth it.  Best bet is software license agreements which would make it a violation of your contract if a customer modifies your code.

Comment: No one to edit it? Easy: set user permissions at OS level, so no one can edit those. Is that what you want or do you mean to obfuscate?

Comment: there is no 100% perfect method - if this is a distributed script. licensing is the best option if its commercial.

Comment: Don't give it to people who you don't want to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Ioncube works great, however clients have to have an ioncube decompiler running on their server.